# MYSQL Generate Columns from Group of rows using PHP or MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pivot

I want to dynamically generate columns from rows. In the Subject Field of my table, I have five difference subjects, but the number of subjects may vary, sometimes it will be more than five or less than 4. My code can identify the number of subjects using php array and mysql group by Subject:

```
SELECT regd, Subject, SUM( Mark_score ) / SUM( Full_Mark ) *100 AS hl, 
SUM( Full_Mark ) AS hm
FROM entry
WHERE Year = '2013'
AND Section = 'A'
AND Name_of_exam = 'First Term Exam'
GROUP BY regd, Subject
```

See the image: http://s11.postimg.org/yykmxgnv7/outpt.jpg

For Selecting one record:

```
SELECT regd, Subject, SUM( Mark_score ) / SUM( Full_Mark ) *100 AS hl, 
SUM( Full_Mark ) AS hm
FROM cxexam
WHERE regd='332' AND Year = '2013'
AND Section = 'A'
AND Name_of_exam = 'First Term Exam'
GROUP BY Subject
```

This is doing fine. Now I want to output like [this](http://s17.postimg.org/5s1ng600v/queryexpect.jpg) using the following code:

```
$sub=array();
$query=mysql_query("SELECT regd, Subject, 
SUM( Mark_score ) / SUM( Full_Mark ) *100 AS hl, 
SUM( Full_Mark ) AS hm
FROM entry
WHERE Year = '2013'
AND Section = 'A'
AND Name_of_exam = 'First Term Exam'
GROUP BY regd, Subject");
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){ 
    $sub[$row['Subject']] = $row['hl'];
}
$all=array_values($sub);
$dan=array_keys($sub);
$length=count($all);

        echo "<table border=1>";
        echo "<tr>";
            for($i=0;$i<=$length;$i++){
                   echo "<td>".$dan[$i]."</td>";
            }
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
            for($j=0;$j<=$length;$j++){
        echo '<td>'.$all[$j].'</td>';
            }
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
```

The output is wrong and does not generate the rows. It returns only two rows, expected is five rows. I really need everyone's help.

Comment: What's the output look like? You should have two rows...

Comment: @Ic, I have just two rows while I expect five rows. I just edited the questions. Sorry for mistakes.

Comment: Why would you expect five rows? You've very clearly specified two. Have you copied your code correctly?

Comment: My code is working for just single record regd record and is not working for multiple rows record. Please have a look at the image link provided in the question. I am newbie anyway.

Comment: I believe your problem is caused by `$sub[$row['Subject']] = $row['hl'];`, as you are overwriting the value on each loop. So instead of getting all rows, you are only getting the last -> ie. only `redg`=350, but not 319,328,332. Also, you will also need to put your 2nd table row loop around the row, not just the cell.

Comment: @Sean, please can you show me a sample code to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you were overwriting each `Subject` value, and not storing them based off the `regd`. This can be accomplished by using `$sub[$row['regd']][$row['Subject']]`. Then you need to loop through each `regd` to get each `Subject` value. Something like ->

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){ 
    $sub[$row['regd']][$row['Subject']] = $row['hl']; //create an array row based on the regd
}
$subkey=key($sub); //get the 1st regd key, to be used to get the Subject keys

        echo "<table border=1>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo '<td>regd</td>';
            foreach($sub[$subkey] as $keys=>$vals){ //loop through each of the Subject keys from the 1st regd
                   echo "<td>".$keys."</td>";
            }
        echo "</tr>";

            foreach($sub as $key=>$val){ //loop through each regd value, creating a row
        echo "<tr>";
        echo '<td>'.$key.'</td>';
            foreach($val as $v){ //loop through each Subjects for each regd
        echo '<td>'.$v.'</td>';
            }
        echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
```

Comment: I begin to understand array. Suppose I want to add one or more columns (likely to hold string) after regd column in the sql statement, how do I print out that field in your existing answer. Your input is greatly appreciated. I have been trying to achieve since 6 hours ago but was at loss.